# CSS 5 star rating System, star span issue

Tags: css, rating-system

I have created a 5 star rating system. My css is set up to display grey background stars which are fixed on the screen. When hovered over blue stars appear, although these stars are centered and span out, for example when I select 1 star, the middle star turns gold instead of the left most grey star, likewise if I select 2 stars, two gold stars appear between the second and fourth grey stars, with the grey stars still visable in the background. This looks very untidy.

Can anyone advise how I can change my code to turn the actual stars that is selected gold?

My stars image is stars.png which has a grey, blue and gold star respectively in one image.

My knowledge of css is limited. I have tried changing multiple components of the css one by one such as width or px but to no avail.

Here is my css.

```
form .stars {
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form .stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
  width: 100%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
  width: 80%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
  width: 60%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
  width: 40%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
  width: 20%;
}
form .stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .stars label:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
  width: 80% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
  width: 60% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
  width: 40% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
  width: 20% !important;
}
form .stars span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Um, could you remove the line numbers?

Comment: Hi @JacobGray. I have removed the line numbers as requested. They were not in my actual code by the way

Comment: Essentially it comes down to changing the `background-position` attribute. You move the background image so the "state" of the star you want is showing. I can't provide exact code because I don't know what your star sprite looks like.

Comment: Here's a pretty solid example that uses `input:checked ~ label:before` to apply the style to the currently checked radio and any "lower" value radios. http://codepen.io/lsirivong/pen/ekBxI

Comment: Here's the same example, but I've tinkered with it to simplify it just a bit.  https://jsfiddle.net/ve3m7vxe/

Comment: Hi @Scott. My sprites are in one image stacked on top of each other. Grey star on top, blue star in the middle and gold star at the bottom if this helps?

Comment: Hi @Anthony. I tried your example though it wouldnt quite work with my current setup. The rest of my page is on a white background I removed the code for this but the stars would not display correctly, I just received a black rectangle with no stars showing. Would you be able to change the code to have a white background, and the stars to have a black or grey outline then gold when selected?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a more compact solution to that 5 star-rating code. It involves reversing the way the adjacent selectors work using:

```
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
direction: rtl;
```

This demo uses a simple font which makes it faster than the conventional `<img>` or sprites, and as a font, it is subject to `color`, `font-size`, `font-style`, etc.

Read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) for details.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/exIquWnDJkTW2sOKAUEP?p=preview)

**Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <title>Star Ratings</title>
  <style>
    .rate {
      unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .rate> span {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 1.1em;
    }
    .rate > span:hover,
    .rate > span:hover ~ span {
      color: transparent;
    }
    .rate > span:hover:before,
    .rate > span:hover ~ span:before {
      content: "\2605";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      color: gold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <aside class="rate">
    <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne tried this but there stars dont display for, as the rest of my page is set up with css. I just get strange symbols where the stars should be

Comment: To clarify the stars do appear when hovered over, but an "a" with a "~" symbol on top appears when the supposed stars on in normal state

Comment: Are you using the exact code I provided? Or did you take the important portions of the code and then integrated it within your page? If the latter, then I suspect that your page needs this `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>`

Comment: I did use the exact code you suggested, I have other code on my page to work out the average rating etc so I suspect it is conflicting with that, or because I am using Internet Explorer browser

Comment: Do you have `<!doctype html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> ` and `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the very top. Your page is not displaying unicode properly.